# Error with Tomcat service.bat install

Tags: windows-services, tomcat7

When I'm trying run below code,

```
D:\apache-tomcat\bin>service.bat install
```

I got this error.

```
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

How could I solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found answer for my question. I should add,

```
set JAVA_HOME=<JAVA INSTALLED Location>
```

just before `set "CURRENT_DIR=%cd%"` in `service.bat` file locate in `bin` directory in tomcat installed directory.

Comment: You don't have to modify `service.bat` per se, you can just enter the `set ...` command before calling `service.bat`

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to define environment variable JAVA_HOME and point it to java installed location.

or

you can add below line in in TOMCAT_HOME\bin\startup.bat

```
set 'JAVA_HOME=<JAVA INSTALLED Location>'
```

2.If JDK is not installed in your machine, define JRE_HOME and point to installed JRE

Comment: i have added that. but not worked. to where should i add that line ? any where in file ? or is there any specific location ?

Comment: add in Tomcat_home\bin\startup.bat just before set "CURRENT_DIR=%cd%" line

Comment: That doesn't help when calling `service.bat`.